# run apache beam on apache flink

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

I want to run a Python code using Apache beam on Apache Flink. The command that the apache beam site for launching Python code on Apache Flink is as follows:

```
docker run --net=host apachebeam/flink1.9_job_server:latest --flink-master=localhost:8081
```

The following is a discussion of different methods of executing code using Apache Fail on Apache Flink. But I haven't seen an example of launching it.

https://flink.apache.org/ecosystem/2020/02/22/apache-beam-how-beam-runs-on-top-of-flink.html

I want this code to run without Docker. How is this code commanded?

Comment: This is the documentation I found: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/flink/#executing-a-beam-pipeline-on-a-flink-cluster. If you are looking for methods beyond what the doc says, you can send an email to dev@beam.apache.org to discuss that.

Comment: I read this page. That's the problem. To use apache beam in Apache flink, he used Docker. I want to find another way to get started. Is there another way to use beam in flink?

Comment: Sorry I don't know if there is another way. But if there is one, dev@beam.apache.org should know because devs there developed solutions about beam on flink

Answer (score 1):

You can spin up the flink job server directly using the beam source source. Note you'll need to install java.

1) Clone the beam source code:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/beam.git
```

2) Start the job server

```
cd beam
./gradlew -p runners/flink/1.8/job-server runShadow -PflinkMasterUrl=localhost:8081
```

Some helpful tips:

This is not flink itself! You'll need to spin up flink separately.

The flink job service actually spins up a few services:

- Expansion Service (port 8097) : This service allows you to use ExternalTransforms within your pipeline that exist within the java sdk. For example the transforms found within the python sdk `apache_beam.io.external.*` hit this expansion service.
- Artifact Service (port 8098) : This is where the pipeline uploads your python artifacts (e.g. pickle files, etc) to be used by the flink taskmanager when it executes your python code. From what I recall you must share the artifact staging area (default to `/tmp/beam-artifact-staging`) between the flink taskworker and this artifact service.
- Job Service (port 8099) : This is what you submit your pipeline to. It translates your pipeline into something for flink and submits it.